# AWS EMR add step: How to add multiple jars from s3 in --jars and --driver-class-path options?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, spark-submit

So I am trying to run an `Apache Spark` application on AWS EMR in `cluster` mode using `spark-submit`. If I have only one jar to provide in the classpath, it works fine with given option using the `--jar` and `--driver-class-path` options. All of my required dependency jars are located in `S3` bucket as required by EMR. I am using below command for that purpose in EMR add step option on the EMR AWS console:

```
--class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher --jars s3://emrb/gson-2.8.4.jar --driver-class-path s3://emrb/gson-2.8.4.jar
```

Now, I provide this option in the `spark-submit options` area in the `add step`. But if I want to provide multiple dependent jars using the same way, it does not takes up the other jars. I am providing following way and have tried various options but it cannot find the dependent jars:

```
 --jars s3://emrb/hadoop_jars/emrfs-hadoop-assembly-2.32.0.jar,s3://emrb/gson-2.8.4.jar --driver-class-path s3://emrb/hadoop_jars/emrfs-hadoop-assembly-2.32.0.jar,s3://emrb/gson-2.8.4.jar --class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

Answer (score 0):

You could specify steps parameters in a separate json file :

```bash
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id "j-xxx" --steps file://./steps.json
```

with steps.json containing something like :

```json
[
  {
    "Type":"Spark",
    "Args": [
      "--jars",
      "s3://emrb/hadoop_jars/emrfs-hadoop-assembly-2.32.0.jar,s3://emrb/gson-2.8.4.jar",
      "--driver-class-path",
      "s3://emrb/hadoop_jars/emrfs-hadoop-assembly-2.32.0.jar,s3://emrb/gson-2.8.4.jar",
      "--class",
      "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add the jar files in the spark-defaults. If there is more than one entry in the jars list, use : as separator.

you should use:

--driver-class-path s3://emrb/hadoop_jars/emrfs-hadoop-assembly-2.32.0.jar:s3://emrb/gson-2.8.4.jar

Comment: Have you tried it? Because `:` is generally separator here which comes in s3 classpath/ Hence it fails to take multiple entries that way.